# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /

Tags: php

can anyone help me parse error I keep getting with this code plus the div tags are not working either so maybe you could give me a explanation thanks in advance .

```
<?php
        if (isset($errors) === false){
            echo 'Click to update and edit your profile.'; 
        }else if (empty($errors)){
             echo 'Your profile has been updated.'
        }else{
                echo '<ul><li>',implode('</li></li>',$errors), </li</ul>';
         ?>
        </div>
        <form action"" method="post">
             <div>
                  <label for="email">Email:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $user_info['email']; ?>" />
             </div>
             <div>
```

Comment: You're missing a single quote after before `</li</ul>';

Comment: thanks cant believe i didn't notice that

Comment: I think you want to implode() with '</li><li>' between the $errors elements. And you're missing a > too, not just a '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
        if (isset($errors) === false)
        {
            echo 'Click to update and edit your profile.'; 
        }
        elseif (empty($errors)){
             echo 'Your profile has been updated.';
        }else{
                echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li></li>',$errors).' </li</ul>';
      }
         ?>
        </div>
        <form action"" method="post">
             <div>
                  <label for="email">Email:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $user_info['email']; ?>" />
             </div>
             <div>
```

Comment: the line in question should probably be `echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$errors).' </li></ul>';`